# How can I resolve a sparse SSH connection latency/delay issues

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

## Synopsis

For months I've occasionally been having problems with SSH connections to dedicated servers - I'm talking every single server I connect to, from multiple locations and the servers being various distributions of Linux.

The problem is that once I have connected via SSH, the initial connection is instantaneous as expected when I'm typing some of the time the characters appear in the `Terminal` instantly, other times I can be waiting from 1 - 4 seconds and then a chunk of characters appears...

## Attempted steps to resolve

I have attempted Google searches but most results come back as latency issues with the initial SSH connection, or connection timeouts - these are *NOT* the issue i'm having.

I'm not sure how to debug this further; if it's a bug in Terminal, a configuration issue with `Terminal.app` or even an `ssh_config` issue specific to UNIX/BSD...

How can I debug this further? Is there any known information regarding this behaviour?

## Update

Also, when i connect to 4G via hotspot tethering i still get the same problem...

Comment: How did you discount the connection latency issues?

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: *I have attempted Google searches but most results come back as latency issues with the initial SSH connection, or connection timeouts - these are NOT the issue i'm having.*  ***How did you determine this wasn't the issue?***

Comment: @Allan because i'm not being disconnected, there is no broken pipe ssh wont disconnected after 10 seconds and within a 10 second period of being connected via SSH the latency starts almost instantly (it's not an internet issue because it happens on every connection including leased lines)